# What can I do, being on a Tenure-track position and noticing that the promised start-up package, course release and ... were just false promises?

Tags: united-states, tenure-track

This fall I started a tenure track position. They offered me a very good start-up package. Half of it was state money for buying equipment and the other half was for course release, research assistants, travel and etc. Also I had a promise for spouse support and that had huge impact on accepting the offer (unfortunately this one was not written!).

Now, I see that the only thing I can use is the state money which is more than enough. However, the equipment is not the only thing I need. Obviously, I need students for my research too. It's my second semester and they  have not even sent me my written contact yet. Their false promises have put me and my family in a very difficult situation.

What can I do now? What are my rights? Obviously, I am not planning to stay here. But cannot leave off without doing anything. I do not want other families go through the same situation as me! Other faculty members have almost same issues but no hope for any change.

Note: for the start-package I have an email as proof. Also, initially, the university was required to pay equal amount as state money to new faculties.

Comment: How were you hired without a written contract? What country?

Comment: I'm rather amazed that you have even gotten paid without some sort of contract...you have gotten paid sometime since you started, right?

Comment: Do you mean a position for Fall 2021 that hasn't yet started?

Comment: It's in united states and yes it's tenured track position and just recently  I was evaluated by committee members!  At the time of offer, they told me because of COVID there is delay in sending contracts. After I joined here they told me it's prepared but have a lazy HR ! Initially I just had an email from provost! mentioning the money and the fact that it is tenure track! I'm receiving  200K money for my research from state and it's only for tenure track faculty!

Comment: Before coming here I contacted some other tenured professors. They told me don't worry about contract we also got very late!

Comment: My position started Fall 2020!

Comment: It's a state university!

Comment: Yes, I got paid from the start with all the benefits like retirement, insurance, ...

Comment: I just had finished my PhD from a very good university! I didn't expected this amount of dishonesty in any university in U.S.

Comment: I have even have more to say! I applied for a fellowship. A very famous fellowship within the Universities of (my state) and I received an email from president that I have been awarded the fellowship! but no money was mentioned! This money was donated by a famous guy. I asked dean several times, I talked with senior faculties and they said this how corrupted here is! I have told all the issues to our faculty senate!

Comment: Keep careful records of everything you've discussed, make sure you send an email after every in person conversation with a summary of what was discussed / promised and insist on getting your contract finalized ASAP. I don't know what other advice you could possibly be expecting to get.

Comment: Thank you! yes I have records of emails. I need help from faculties who work at state universities! what office can I go? is there any offices within such systems for such cases? I only see faculty Councils which I am not sure is the right office to contact!

Comment: For my next year, I have TT offers from much better schools. I don't care about current contact. The only thing is that what legal options I have to sue them or even at least report within the system.

Comment: If you want legal options (which makes sense) then you should consult a lawyer.

Comment: If you have offers now you've been interviewing through the start of your current job? This doesn't exactly feel on the level anymore.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My strong advice is that you take an offer from a better school and just do what is needed to get through the year as best you can. If the place is as bad as this then you, with little institutional power behind you, aren't going to make a difference. You will be stomped like a bug. I was once in a bad situation (perhaps not this bad) and went for the door by the shortest route possible, simply saying goodby to the insanity. It worked out fine. As in your case, I wasn't going to get anything from any other action.

In particular don't say things that might come back to negatively affect your own career. Suing them might be an option, but it requires a hard talk with a lawyer first and threatening it isn't going to get you a positive outcome.

I realize this is hard advice to take, but you have a good option and you don't want to do things that antagonize people and that will cause blow-back on yourself.

You are fortunate to have a good option. Take it. Others aren't so lucky.

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind advice. Probably that was the best that I needed to hear! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The email you got from the provost is the only contract you have until you get a new contract.

> What can I do now? What are my rights?

Ask a lawyer.

If the email you got from the provost does not provide you with what you want, then you should leave the job.

Comment: Anything other than "ask a lawyer" from someone who has not seen the email and read your local law could be very wrong.

Comment: If you have a union, you could ask your union's lawyer.

Comment: I'm not a lawyer, either, but I worry that letters, as opposed to contracts, might be filled with "weasel words" that cover them. But, yes, if you contemplate legal action, the only proper course is to do it after consulting a lawyer and that consultation prior to any threats to sue.